# Azure Function - SqlConnection connection pool & timeouts

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure-functions, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-functions-runtime

Note - I have read the other topics on S.O about this but not quite the same...

.net 461 function, c#

I have an app-service-environment with an app service plan dedicated to this single azure function, using 2x P2 workers.

The function itself responds to a service bus topic event, at a rate of about 1-2 per second - and in response we are writing data away via a stored procedure to a SQL server in a data centre.

In our pre-production environment where load is drastically less, we see no issue. Under production load as indicated above, we consistently get 2 SQL error messages:

1 - SqlException - timeout occurred, this may be due to the connection pool being out of connections

Then after the first instance of this message, consistently every function run will then give the default

2 - SqlException - timeout occurred, network instance could be reached, etc.. please check if SQL server is there

Have had network staff check and traffic is hitting the SQL server ports, but no connections are present in the actual SQL server connection list.

Our c# code, whilst I can't post the actual code, is incredibly simple - a single Stored Procedure call made via Dapper wrapped in a using block.

```
using(var sqlConnection = new sqlConnection("connString"))
{
    sqlConnection.Open();
    // setup input params here
    // execute sproc here
    sqlConnection.Close(); // I know, shouldn't need this line when using a using block - but thought would check.
}
```

What we don't understand is on the very first function invocation after re-starting the entire app-service - we get the connection pool error straight away, followed by the timeouts.

Our SqlConnection string contains no specific changes to pool size, or timeouts (so should be all SQL defaults) - the only thing is the production SQL server runs on a non-standard port (but that is accessible).

Two things to mind:

1 - Should we be using OpenAsync() and ExecuteAynsc() - or should synchronous versions still suffice given our load is not incredibly high.

2 - Is there any specific to an App Service Environment which changes what happens with connection string pooling?

Thanks in advance

## Edit

As requested:

async Task RunAsync(BrokeredMessage message, TraceWriter log) {}

Datacentre SQL Server is Sql Server Enterprise 2008R2

Average duration when calls work in non-production, is 250-300ms (we have Express Route)

Payload - Very small, 5-8 string fields being passed as parameters

Comment: Can you tell us if you are talking to a "standard" SQL server or an Azure SQL server instance?

Comment: Could you add your function signature? Do you do any Task/async operations?

Comment: How long does the proc execution take (including network latency? I can see these symptoms if the duration exceeds the incoming rate filling the pool with active connections.

Comment: Have you tried ommiting the actual stored proc call? Or just putting something that will 'wait' 1-2 secs with open connections without trying to grab locks on the DB?

Comment: Have edited the post to cater to comments. Function itself is an async Task RunAsync(BrokeredMessage message, TraceWriter log). Haven't tried the blank-wait approach yet, it's something we could try. The thing that really gets me is after entirely re-starting the app service as a whole, the very first call gets the connection pool error.... this just doesn't feel right?

Comment: Do you have any visibility into your SQL server? Are you sure you're not just running into a situation when executing the sproc where all of your requests are ending up serialized? The message "this may be due to the connection pool being out of connections" could be a bit of a red-herring. It *may be* running out of connections, but it could also just be that your command timed out.

Comment: I did wonder if this wasn't actually a connection pool issue on the Azure Function side - and just a really odd message to get back. I can get visibility into the SQL server via the DBA's - they said they couldn't see connections but the networking team said they did.

Comment: Yeah we use a tool from Solarwinds that gives us some really nice reports on locking/blocking issues, but there's plenty of other tools out there and, worst case, you can spot this stuff just by using Activity Monitor in SSMS or even just executing some system sprocs if you have to. You're just trying to spot any contention around whatever resources that sproc is acting on. If you own the sproc code, you can probably just review it for what kinds of locks it might be taking/requiring.

Comment: Could you check if removing `Task` from function helps? No explanation for that, but I saw the same in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this figured out - the Connection pool draining error message was a frustrating red herring.

Standard network firewall issue!!

Thank you all